# Obter a hora em a partir de uma planilha excell

Tags: java, datetime, apache-poi

Estou usando o POI api in Java. Para obter a hora em uma planilha excel.
Na planilha de excell o dado esta como texto

**imagem**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public void obterHora(){
    Cell hora = row.getCell(7);
    System.out.println("hora: "+hora);
}
```

> resultado: 31-dez-1899

Durante o debug obtiver essa dado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para este problema foi essa:

```
public void obterHora(){
    String hora;
    int h=row.getCell(7).getDateCellValue().getHours();
    int m=row.getCell(7).getDateCellValue().getMinutes();
    int s=row.getCell(7).getDateCellValue().getSeconds();

    hora = h+":"+m+":"+s;

    SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date data = formatador.parse(horario);
    horaAgen = new Time(data.getTime());

    System.out.println("hora: "+horaAgen);
}
```

Resultado:

> 9:00:00 
>   12:00:00

sempre no formato

> HH:mm:ss

Dessa forma atendeu as minhas necessidades